# How to open iframe in another iframe from different/external html file

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to open an iframe in another iframe from the external file. For instance:

index.html file

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>

    <head>
     <title>Iframe 1</title>
    </head>

    <body style="text-align: center; background-color: #F4D03F; color: #333;margin: 0; padding: 0;position: absolute;width: 100%;height: 100%;">
     <h1>Iframe 1</h1>
     <iframe id="iframe" style="border: 0; position: absolute; display: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0; top: 0"></iframe>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Second file called iframe2.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Iframe 2</title>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center; background-color: #F4D03F; color: #333;margin: 0; padding: 0;position: absolute;width: 100%;height: 100%;">
    <h1>Iframe 2</h1>
    <iframe id="iframe" style="border: 0; position: absolute; display: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0; top: 0"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

and I would like to open the same identical file but as an iframe 2, after the first one **is loaded**.
So it would be kind of the nested iframes but in separate html files.
Is it overall possible?

Answer (score 0):

So you're meaning something like :

```js
if2.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  let if3 = document.createElement('iframe');
  if3.id="if3";
  if1.appendChild(if3);
  });
```

```css
iframe{height:250px;width:250px;border:1px solid black;}
#if3{height:50px;width:50px;}
```

```html
<iframe id="if1"></iframe>
<iframe id="if2"></iframe>
```

also the word window in javascript is global so if it's called in a nested iframe you can get it back in the main document.

here is an exemple that shows window in action :

https://jsfiddle.net/josewirewax/2rqnsdd6/

and another one with lots of iframes

http://jsfiddle.net/asicfr/670uc0ve/

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. I mean rather open the next iframe on onload event and then the next iframe window and so on...